# How can I create overlapping table rows with borders without box-shadow for email?

Tags: html

I need to create a table in an email where some cells have borders but the cell on the next row down overlaps the border of the row above. I can create that using:

```html
<table style="width: 100%; background-color: #dcdcdc;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="4" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
<div style="height: 30px; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; box-shadow: 10px 10px red; background-color: yellow;">Primary Info</div>
</td>
<td style="width: 40px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 40px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="4" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
<div style="height: 30px; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; box-shadow: 10px 10px red; background-color: green;">Secondary Info</div>
</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="6" style="line-height: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The problem is that neither gmail nor yahoo email's readers honor box-shadows and so the result people receive on gmail/yahoo see is the boxes without borders and the text pushed to the top left instead of centered in each box.

I thought I could just specify cell widths in a table to mimic the box-shadow appearance and so to that end I wrote this:

```html
<table style="width: 100%; background-color: #dcdcdc;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>

<tr style="line-height: 10px;">
<td colspan="4" style="background-color: yellow;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr style="line-height: 10px;">
<td colspan="4" style="background-color: yellow;" align="center" valign="middle">Primary Info</td>
<td style="width: 10px; background-color: red;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr style="line-height: 10px;">
<td colspan="4" style="background-color: yellow;" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 10px; background-color: red;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr style="line-height: 10px;">
<td style="width: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 10px; background-color: red;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 10px; background-color: red;">&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="4" style="background-color: green;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr style="line-height: 10px;">
<td style="width: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="4" style="background-color: green;" align="center" valign="middle">Secondary Info</td>
<td style="width: 10px; background-color: red;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr style="line-height: 10px;">
<td style="width: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="4" style="background-color: green;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 10px; background-color: red;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr style="line-height: 10px;">
<td style="width: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="4" style="background-color: red;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

but the widths I'm specifying in the table aren't being honored by the browser displaying the table.

I know I could use colspan and rowspan above to make it the HTML more compact but I was trying to keep it as simple as possible and remove anything that might be interacting to cause my problem.

I THINK that since I'm sending this in email I can't write CSS at the top and so I need all commands to be specified as HTML so that's what I'm doing and what I'm looking for help to complete.

I've been working on this for days and tried hundreds of options but trial and error is consistently producing error! Anyone know why my width values are being ignored and what I need to do to get the table layout I need without box-shadow and CSS?

---

Result of suggestion in comment below to use with=20 (I assume you meant width=10) is no difference:

```html
<table style="width: 100%; background-color: #dcdcdc;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>

<tr style="line-height: 10px;">
<td colspan="4" style="background-color: yellow;">&nbsp;</td>
<td width=10>&nbsp;</td>
<td width=10>&nbsp;</td>
<td width=10>&nbsp;</td>
<td width=10>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr style="line-height: 10px;">
<td colspan="4" style="background-color: yellow;" align="center" valign="middle">Primary Info</td>
<td width=10 style="background-color: red;">&nbsp;</td>
<td width=10>&nbsp;</td>
<td width=10>&nbsp;</td>
<td width=10>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr style="line-height: 10px;">
<td colspan="4" style="background-color: yellow;" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td width=10 style="background-color: red;">&nbsp;</td>
<td width=10>&nbsp;</td>
<td width=10>&nbsp;</td>
<td width=10>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr style="line-height: 10px;">
<td width=10>&nbsp;</td>
<td width=10 style="background-color: red;">&nbsp;</td>
<td width=10 style="background-color: red;">&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="4" style="background-color: green;">&nbsp;</td>
<td width=10>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr style="line-height: 10px;">
<td width=10>&nbsp;</td>
<td width=10>&nbsp;</td>
<td width=10>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="4" style="background-color: green;" align="center" valign="middle">Secondary Info</td>
<td width=10 style="background-color: red;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr style="line-height: 10px;">
<td width=10>&nbsp;</td>
<td width=10>&nbsp;</td>
<td width=10>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="4" style="background-color: green;">&nbsp;</td>
<td width=10 style="background-color: red;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr style="line-height: 10px;">
<td width=10>&nbsp;</td>
<td width=10>&nbsp;</td>
<td width=10>&nbsp;</td>
<td width=10>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="4" style="background-color: red;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you try to specify the width like this <td width=20 >&nbsp;</td>

Comment: That made no difference. I edited the question to show it at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

idk why the HTML in the question doesn't work but the following does work, which I arrived at by drawing a table in Word, saving that in HTML, and then stripping the irrelevant parts and tweaking cell dimensions:

```html
<table style="width: 100%; background-color: #dcdcdc;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

 <tr style="line-height: 10px;">
  <td colspan=4 rowspan=3 style='text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; background:yellow;'>Primary Info</td>
  <td style='width:10px;'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td style='width:30px;'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td style='width:10px;'>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>

 <tr style="line-height: 10px;">
  <td rowspan=2 style='width:10px; background:red;'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td style='width:30px;'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td style='width:10px;'>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>

 <tr style="line-height: 10px;">
  <td style='width:30px;'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td style='width:10px;'>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>

 <tr style="line-height: 10px;">
  <td style='width:10px;'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td style='width:40px; background:red;'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td colspan=4 rowspan=3 style='text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; background:green;'>Secondary Info</td>
  <td style='width:10px;'>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>

 <tr style="line-height: 10px;">
  <td style='width:10px;'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td style='width:40px;'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td rowspan=2 style='width:10px; background:red;'>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>

 <tr style="line-height: 10px;">
  <td style='width:10px;'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td style='width:40px;'>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>

 <tr style="line-height: 10px;">
  <td style='width:10px;'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td style='width:40px;'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td style='width:10px;'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td colspan=4 style='background:red;'>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>

</table>
```